# Using action in Javascript to submit form

Tags: javascript, forms, action

I'm trying to submit a form using javascript. This is the code I've used to set the action to the form and then submit it. These 2 lines are in the onclick method defined for a button.

```
document.form1.action = fin_string;
document.forms["form1"].submit();
```

The problem here is that the fin_string gets replaced by something else when I do this. For eg. when fin_string = "http://www.gmail.com" this works, however when I keep fin_string as some other string (relative to the current path with attached parameters) it gets changed. alert(fin_string), shows the string correctly but when I use the string to set the action on the form and submit it, it gets changed.

This is what I want the fin_string to be (relative to the current path)

```
remote-service/FeedMergerManualTrigger?locales=en_GB-en_SG&deleteOutputFile=Y&localFilePath=c:/go/
```

but this is what the browser goes to when I assign it an action and submit the form.

```
remote-service/FeedMergerManualTrigger?LMN=UK&ZJ=SG&localResourcesMode=on&EUPath=c:/go/&delete_op=Y.
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Is your form using `GET` as `method`? Seems to me that your problem is not with the string but that the form is setting the values (correctly) based on the input fields within. Are the parameters sent existing as fields within the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have such code instead, it will assign hidden form elements instead of adding to the query string thus it won't get changed:

```
var fin_string = "remote-service/FeedMergerManualTrigger";
var arrData = {"locales": "en_GB-en_SG", "deleteOutputFile": "Y", "localFilePath": "c:/go/"};
var oForm = document.forms["form1"];
oForm.action = fin_string;
for (var key in arrData)
    AddOrUpdate(oForm, key, arrData[key]);
//encodeURIComponent(arrData[key])
oForm.submit();

function AddOrUpdate(oForm, sName, sValue) {
    var oInput = oForm.elements[sName];
    if (!oInput) {
        oInput = document.createElement("input");
        oInput.type = "hidden";
        oInput.name = sName;
        oForm.appendChild(oInput);
    }
    oInput.value = sValue;
}
```